# ASP MVC 5, Route Not Found

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Using a mixture of attribute named routing and standard conventional routing.

I have a `UserController` with two 'Create' actions. One is a `HTTPGet` for getting the view, and one is a `HTTPPost` for posting the data back.

Here is that entire controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("User")]
public class UserController : Controller {
    public UserController() {}

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create() {
        return View();
    }

    [Route("Create")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> CreateAsync(UserM m) {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
            return View(m);
        }

        var user = new User() {
            Email = m.Email,
            Forename = m.Forename,
            IsActive = true,
            Surname = m.Surname
        };


        return Redirect("");    
    }
}
```

**However when I try to navigate to User/Create from the submit button on the site, to post the data back, I get a 404.**

Here is the route config:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    // Turn on attribute routing in the controllers
    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Here is the view that posts the data back:

```
@model MyApp.WebMS.Models.UserM
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create User";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="xs-12">
            <h3>Create User</h3>
            <hr class="no-top-margin" />
        </div>
    </div>

    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <h4>Personal Information</h4>
                <div class="user-creation-section">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Forename, new { @class = "form-label" })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Forename, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Surname, new { @class = "form-label" })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Surname, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-label" })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <h4>Job Information</h4>
                <div class="user-creation-section">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.JobTitle, new { @class = "form-label" })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.JobTitle, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.StartDate, new { @class = "form-label" })
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartDate, new { type = "date", @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="xs-12 pull-right">
                <input type="button" class="btn" value="Back" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "Home")'" />
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: How have you defined the `<form>` in your view

Comment: Yes I have, the view is fine.

Comment: I asked how, not if :)

Comment: Oh my bad, Ill edit OP

Comment: @BenDonnelly, I have tested your code and worked. Is it possible that this is not exactly what you're running? For example, do you have `return Redirect("");` at the end of your action method?

Comment: try to change [Route("Create")]  to [ActionName("Create")]

Answer (score 0):

Since your `POST` action is named CreateAsync, you'll have to explicitly mention that in your form.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateAsync", "User", FormMethod.Post))
```

Comment: Ah I thought named attribute would've gotten around that

Comment: @Zahed, when you first visit the page by GET, current url is "user/create". By default `Html.BeginForm()` without parameters, should be posting to current url which is "user/create". So the question persists, why this code not routing correctly?